# access spinnaker api using curl

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spinnaker

I am trying to use api methods to manage spinnaker, creating pipelines if have to be specific. Reason for not using spin cli or other tools is plan to launch this automation at aws lambda. using google oauth and get methods are working fine when using browser. but when try to do same with curl get no response. Wondering whats missing in my curl command:

`curl command.curl -X GET "http://spinnaker-api.mydomain.com//applications"`

would really be grateful I can get some context on this. I think its missing authentication header but wondering what fields should be provided?.

Thanks